# failed to get img displayed using forEach in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render image from my api, I first used size of lodash to check the array is empty or not, if it's empty display the upload button, else just render the images.

When I do

`{item.photos.toString()}` I'm able to see the url but why below code just doesn't work? no error at all in my console.

```
<div id="photo_upload">
    {size(item.photos) > 1 ? 
    item.photos.forEach(photo =>{
       <img src={photo} />
    })
    : <div><button>Upload</buton>
    </div>}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`forEach` doesn't return anything, so that operand in your conditional will have the value `undefined`. You wanted `map` (and `return` inside it). Also note your closing button tag for the Upload button is missing a `t` (fixed below):

```
<div id="photo_upload">
    {size(item.photos) > 1 ? 
    item.photos.map(photo =>{
       return <img src={photo} />;
    })
    : <div><button>Upload</button>
    </div>}
</div>
```

You can also use the concise arrow form:

```
<div id="photo_upload">
    {size(item.photos) > 1 ? 
    item.photos.map(photo => <img src={photo} />)
    : <div><button>Upload</button>
    </div>}
</div>
```

Adding in the points raised by [Đào Minh Hạt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2281853/%c4%90%c3%a0o-minh-h%e1%ba%a1t) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42620714/157247) (`> 0` rather than `> 1`, and `key`):

```
<div id="photo_upload">
    {size(item.photos) > 0 ? 
    item.photos.map(photo => <img key={photo} src={photo} />)
    : <div><button>Upload</button>
    </div>}
</div>
```

Comment: the first block of code and second, why one need return one isn't? put the statement in the same line then return is not needed? I'm confused.

Comment: @Mellisa: Arrow functions have two forms: *Verbose* (where you use `{...}` around the function body and need to use `return` to return something), and *concise* (you don't use `{...}` around the body, the body has to be an expression [not a statement], and the result of the expression is automatically returned). Line breaks don't have anything to do with it, it's the `{...}` or lack thereof that makes the difference. I could have written the verbose form all on one line, and I could have written the concise form spread over multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

You use condition `size(item.photos) > 1` only so it won't show if you have only 1 photo.

Another thing is you should add key for each element while doing the loop

```
item.photos.forEach(photo =>{
       <img key={photo} src={photo} />
    })
```

Comment: Between the two of us, we have an answer covering all the issues. :-)